# Holt-Winters Method & Triple Exponential Smoothing

Tags: time-series, exponential-smoothing

what the different about HW method & triple exponential smoothing? Some people say it same. but I still confused about the formula, its look the different.. Please help me, I need for my first research..

Comment: both are same, first search hit in google provided this [link.](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section4/pmc435.htm) The name "triple exponential smoothing" is given because it comprises of **three** components smoothing+trend+seasonal and named after its inventors Holt-Winters. You need to provide more details if you need any further help.

Comment: Yes thanks :) I've seen those web before.. Still many confused about identifying type of data..
for example, I've the data for calculate..
Year  --- Quantity of Sales  
'92 --- 2034
'93 --- 2050
'94 --- 1989
'95 --- 2012
'96 --- 2002
So the data include into trend or seasonal type ? @forecaster

Comment: If you have yearly data then this is not the right method. Since in yearly data there is no seasonality. See [online introductory text](https://www.otexts.org/fpp) for further details if want to learn more about time series forecasting.

Comment: Ok. thnx. now I'll evaluate my data. If there's no seasonality, maybe I must change my method :) Thankyou very much.